# Div scrolling, with parent

Tags: html, css, scroll, mouse

I have a div. And this div contains a very long list. This list becomes scrollable automatically.

This div is then inside another div, which fills out the entire screen.

Scrolling works fine, but it only works when the mouse is over the inner div, the one that actually contains all the data.

But I want scrolling to work, also when the mouse is over the parent div, the one that fills out the entire screen.

How do I do that?

You can see the sample here:
https://openage.org/fs/jsl_forritun/?page=hlutir

It doesn't scroll when the mouse is over the darker part. /:

Comment: Can you share the code ? It will be easier for everyone to understand what you want

Comment: done. ___________

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have two divs that contains your content body

1. id= "nhreyfing"

give him this style `padding: 0 20vw; background: black`
or what so ever padding you wanna give him

2. id= "content"

give him your rgb(213, 191, 134) background

Comment: Sorry about this but ive modified the question slightly. the html is really woodoo magic. ill give a 50 bounty if you can just help me in the right direction with this one.

Comment: you want the scroll to stay on the middle content or is it ok to be on the body ?

Comment: i want to be able to scroll while the mouse is over the darker background.

Comment: my question is, do you care where the scroll will appear ? now it appears in the div do you care if it appears in the body?

Comment: ah the scroll bar, no. its totally fine if it appears in the body i think.

Comment: then my answer stand still,  remove the height:100% from the html

Comment: but when i do that the divs appear below one another. all the pages in the website are stacked up. can remove the height of it and scroll down to see.

Comment: Ok I understand now what your trying to do. 
its pretty smart btw ill edit my answer

Comment: its almost what i need. the problem is when i change the size of the browser the background doesnt fill out correctly anymore.

Comment: yes I showed you a quike solution, you should learn about media query's and responsive theory to make it fit to all screens,
not only you can use flex/grid to solve it too

Comment: ok. question will be eligible for bounty tomorrow. will put it then.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #2B2832;
}

.main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 700px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #D5BF86;
}

.main ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
.main ul li:nth-child(n+2) {
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}

.main ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  color: #000;
  background: #C6B076;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>  
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>  
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>  
        </li>
      <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>  
        </li>
      <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>  
        </li>
      <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>  
        </li>
      <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>  
        </li>
      <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>  
        </li>
      <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>  
        </li>
      <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>  
        </li>
      <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>  
        </li>
      <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>  
        </li>
      <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>  
        </li>
      <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>  
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>  
        </li>
      <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>  
        </li>
      <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>  
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>  
        </li>
      <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>  
        </li>
      <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>  
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>  
        </li>
      <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>  
        </li>
      <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>  
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

- remove CSS properties from 
  **BODY** element {height:100%}
- remove {max-width: 800px} and add CSS to id="initial_screen_base" element:

  div#initial_screen_base {
      max-width: 100vw;
      padding: 0px 20vw;
      background-color: rgb(43, 40, 50);
  }

  - if you want it to me maxed always to 800px (for smaller devices it will be full width), make it like this:

  div#initial_screen_base {
      background-color: rgb(43, 40, 50);
      max-width: 100vw;
      padding: 0;
      padding-right: calc((100% - 800px)/2);
      padding-left: calc((100% - 800px)/2);
  }
- for your id="node":

  div#node {
      background-color: rgb(213, 191, 134);
  }

You should remove you inline CSS and put them in a *style* TAG inside your HEAD. That way you will fave more clear code for yourself to edit.